# Upgrading to Gradle 2.8 breaks my build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I was using Gradle 2.2.1 with Android plugin 1.1.3 and I was a happy man.
However, I decided upgrading to Gradle 2.8 and plugin 1.3.1 and I can't build my project. All I get is an error saying:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.getLocalVersion()
   > Task with name 'xxxxxxxxx' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

This happens whenever I try to build from both Android Studio and command-line.

Any ideas?

PS: My configuration uses the wrapper btw.

Comment: I am not sure that AS supports gradle 2.8. Use gradle 2.5 and plugin 1.3.1

Comment: I can only say(g2.8 + ap:1.3.1):  it's working for me... question is off-topic: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: This is not a "debugging problem". My code is perfectly fine. This is some sort of Gradle/AS configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, you are asking us to debug your gradle/AS configuration. So it's a debugging question.

Comment: @Jolta I don't agree that this is a debugging his configuration, something went wrong when updating. SO was created to answer questions like this, from my perspective.

Comment: @egomez have you tried bumping the classpath to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta4' ???